# Website page width doubles when hovering over div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div a clickable link and was told it is better to put the link inside the div rather than around the div. I noticed that whenever I mouseover one of the divs the webpage suddenly gains an extra 500 or so pixels on the right.

The page isn't supposed to be scrollable, and you can only scroll by holding the middle mouse button and dragging. This happens in Chrome 41.0.2272.101 and Opera 28, but NOT in Firefox 36.0.4.

Here is my code.

HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>John Doe</title>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.11.2.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts.js'></script>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='description' content='Portfolio website displaying projects by John Doe.'>
        <meta name='keywords' content='Portfolio, John Doe, Projects, Software'>
        <meta name='author' content='John Doe'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Top welcome bar. Holds name and description of profession(s). -->
        <div id='welcome_bar'>
            <div id='welcome_bar_name'>John Doe</div>
            <p id='welcome_bar_description'>Software Engineer</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Holds all the navigation "blocks" leading to the about, portfolio,
             contact, and [unused page] pages. -->
        <div id='nav_block'>
            <div id='block_list'>
                <div class='block_container'>
                    <div id='left_out'  class='block'>
                        <a href='webpages/about/about.html'>
                            <!-- Short description of page this block leads to "who I am". -->
                            <div id='about_description' class='block_description'>
                                <p>who I am</p>
                            </div>
                            <p class='block_title'>About Me</p>
                            <div class='block_icon_container'>
                                <img class='block_icon' src='images/about_icon.png' alt='about_icon.png'/>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='block_container'>
                    <div id='left_in'   class='block'>
                        <a href='#'>
                            <!-- Short description of the page this block leads to "what I am proud of". -->
                            <div id='portfolio_description' class='block_description'>
                                <p>what I am proud of</p>
                            </div>
                            <p class='block_title'>Portfolio</p>
                            <div class='block_icon_container'>
                                <img class='block_icon' src='images/portfolio_icon.png' alt='portfolio_icon.png'/>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='block_container'>
                    <div id='right_in'  class='block'>
                        <a href='#'>
                            <div id='sparepage_description' class='block_description'>
                                <p>stuff stuffs</p>
                            </div>
                            <p class='block_title'>Stuff Stuff</p>
                            <div class='block_icon_container'>
                                <img class='block_icon' src='images/stuffstuff_icon.png' alt='stuffstuff_icon.png'/>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='block_container'>
                    <div id='right_out'class='block'>
                        <a href='#'>
                            <div id='contact_description' class='block_description'>
                                <p>let's chat</p>
                            </div>
                            <p class='block_title'>Contact</p>
                            <div class='block_icon_container'>
                                <img class='block_icon' src='images/contact_icon.png' alt='contact_icon.png'/>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS3:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

#welcome_bar {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    left: 12.5%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 10%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto Regular";
    src: url("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
}

#welcome_bar_name {
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 75%;
    height: 50%;
    font-family: Roboto Regular;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    font-size: 3em;
}

#welcome_bar_description {
    position: relative;
    left: 8px;
    top: -15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 35%;
    height: 20%;
    font-family: Roboto Regular;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#nav_block {
    position: relative;
    top: 12%;
    left: 12.5%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 68%;
}

#block_list {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}

.block_container {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 22%;
    height: 100%;
}

.block {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.block a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 10;
}

#left_out {
    width: 99%;
    background-color: #00AE93;
}

#left_in {
    width: 98%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    background-color: #9CA645;
}

#right_in {
    width: 98.5%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    background-color: #EDB613;
}

#right_out {
    width: 99%;
    margin-left: 1.2%;
    background-color: #D55435;
}

#about_description {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: white;
}

#portfolio_description {
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: white;
}

#sparepage_description {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: white;
}

#contact_description {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: white;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Ubuntu M";
    src: url("fonts/Ubuntu-M.ttf");
}

#about_description p {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Ubuntu M;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: #00AE93;
}

#portfolio_description p {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Ubuntu M;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: #9CA645;
}

#sparepage_description p {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Ubuntu M;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: #EDB613;
}

#contact_description p {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Ubuntu M;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: #D55435;
}

.block_icon_container {
    top: 48%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Ubuntu L";
    src: url("fonts/Ubuntu-L.ttf");
}

.block_title {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    top: 45%;
    height: auto;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: Ubuntu L;
    text-align: center;
}

.block_icon {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Under **.block a**, I noticed that if you remove the **width**, the page doesn't expand when you mouse over the block. The size of the percentage seems to effect how far the page is expanded as well.

This bug probably wouldn't be noticed unless visitors randomly scrolled using the middle mouse button, but it bugs me.